# WiFi speed almost halt when Bluetooth is in use - 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, bluetooth, iwlwifi

Computer HP dv7, Centrino chipset.

16.04 was a full reinstall with reformat from 14.04.
In 14.04 this problem was present, home network speed would fall to about 50% if I was using Bluetooth at the same time with WiFi.

But in 16.04 same condition brings WiFi almost to a halt. Web surfing almost impossible. Turning off Bluetooth brings Wifi to normal or alike.

I didn`t find any post related to this problem.

Comment: Please don't use __short hand__ symbols when asking your questions.

Comment: George - could you pls enlighten me about which shorthand?

Comment: You used `w/` twice in your post.

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth coexistent technology in Linux kernel is not perfect when Intel chipsets are used. You can disable it in `iwlwifi` module by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/disable-btcoex.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

The setting will be applied after a reboot.

This setting fixes the issue with Centrino chipsets.

Comment: @ Pilot6 - your code didn`t work this time, but your previous post did.

Comment: sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"

Comment: It does not matter how to call the file. I made a typo here, missed a quote, but now it is fixed.